# Ruby Error FSEVENT on Jekyll build

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

Today i installed Jekyll on my mac. 
Everything have gone fine, i've done it this way:
Install RVM -> Install Ruby through RVM -> Install Jekyll without problems

But now when i try to run my build, it deploys fine but then reports an error. I've included everything i do in the terminal here:

```
Mortens-MacBook-Pro:~ mortenpradsgaard$ cd /Users/mortenpradsgaard/Documents/GitHub
Mortens-MacBook-Pro:GitHub mortenpradsgaard$ cd sostdk
Mortens-MacBook-Pro:sostdk mortenpradsgaard$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/mortenpradsgaard/Documents/GitHub/sostdk/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/mortenpradsgaard/Documents/GitHub/sostdk
       Destination: /Users/mortenpradsgaard/Documents/GitHub/sostdk/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.134 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/mortenpradsgaard/Documents/GitHub/sostdk'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/sostdk//
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
E, [2017-06-29T14:06:16.311105 #5384] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1):/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in configure'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.1/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:75:in `call'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.1/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:52:in `_run'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:78:in `block in start'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:52:in `_run'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:78:in `block in start'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/mortenpradsgaard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
```

Comment: Do oyu have any Gems etc installed in a Bundler file or in the Jekyll-Gem section?

Comment: No, i have not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were facing the same issue in our jekyll build. It turns out this was an issue with the rb-fsevent gem that **should now be resolved as of 0.10.2**.

---

For posterity and future searches, specifying version 0.9.8 in our Gemfile kept us in good shape until the rb-fsevent fix landed:

**Gemfile**

```
gem "rb-fsevent", "0.9.8"
```

Hat tip to https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/431 for the detective work.

Comment: This is the correct answer (but the auto-downvoters already have it at zero--SO is dead).

Comment: I'll check it out as soon, as i can. :) But this is also what i've found on google  atm. Looks promising.

Comment: Nice catch. Please note there is rb-fsevent 0.10.2 now which is said to fix the issue. Maybe you want to update your answer

Comment: Thanks. I just verified that 0.10.2 behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the repository in question? https://github.com/sostdk/sostdk/

In your `_config.yml`, you have the `baseurl` duplicating part of the `siteurl`:

```
siteurl: https://sostdk.github.io/sostdk/
baseurl: /sostdk/
```

It might fix your error if you change `siteurl` to `https://sostdk.github.io/sostdk` and `baseurl` to `/`.

You might want to change your repository name from `sostdk` to `sostdk.github.io`. This would enable you to leave off the `/sostdk` part leaving it just as `https://sostdk.github.io`.

Comment: Oh well it's an error allright. Did no see that, and will be fixed. But i don't think thats whats causing it.